# Facebook graph api: How to get last edit time of user name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know, how can I get the last edit time of facebook user name using facebook graph api.

Comment: @Shadowfax Ok, thanks. Can I get last updated timestamp of profile? OR is it normal to save user's facebook profile name in my database, and when I should update it in my database?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the topic, but I noticed that when the User is viewed as a Map (via the Android API), there is an attribute called `updated_time`.

Here's a snippet that demonstrates:

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(final GraphUser user, final Response response) {
        for (final Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : user.asMap().entrySet()) {
            logger.debug("User {}: {}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Which yields (among other attributes):

```
08-25 17:58:08.531: D/AbstractActivity(21850): User updated_time: 2012-05-25T11:46:32+0000
```